# Show that $P(X<Y) = \int _0^\infty F_X(x)f_Y(x) \ dx$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be nonnegative, independent continuous random
>   variables.
>
> **(a)** Show that $$P(X<Y) = \int _0^\infty F_X(x)f_Y(x) \ dx$$ 
>   **(b)** What does this become if $X ∼ \exp(λ_1)$ and $Y ∼ \exp(λ_2)$?

I don't understand what exactly $P(X<Y)$ means, except for "the probability that the random variable $X$ is less than the random variable $Y$". I think I might be able to solve (b) myself but for (a) I don't know where to start.

Comment: The distribution function of $X-Y$ is like a convolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation of $\mathbb P(X < Y)$ is correct -- the next step is turning that idea into a mathematical expression you can work with.

If you have two random variables with joint density $f(x,y)$, then $\mathbb P(X < Y)$ can be computed as
$$\mathbb P(X < Y) = \iint_{\{x < y\}} f(x, y) \, \textrm d x \, \textrm d y.$$
Since these variables are supported on $[0, \infty)$, one could also write this as
$$\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^y f(x, y) \, \textrm dx \, \textrm dy.$$
But in the case where $X, Y$ are independent, the joint density $f(x,y)$ is just a product of their individual densities. Can you take it from here? (I can provide more hints if not.)

Comment: So, is $P(X<Y)$ basically the joint cdf of $X$ and $Y$, that is $P(X<Y) = F(x,y)$? Now since they are independent, you're saying that their joint pdf is equal to the product of their marginal pdf's? That is $f(x,y) = f_Y(y)\cdot f_X(x)?$

Comment: I don't think I'd agree with the statement that "$P(X<Y)$ is basically the joint cdf of $X$ and $Y$." Rather, think holistically: when you have any continuous variables, and you want to investigate the probability of [thing happening], then your task is universally to integrate an appropriate density function over the region on which [thing happens]. And yes to your comment about joint pdfs.

Comment: But in order to find the marginal PDF's i need to find the joint PDF first, but it's still unknown. According to my book the marginal PDF's are $$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y) \ dy$$ and the same for $f_Y(y)$ but there integration is w.r.t x instead.

Comment: Let me back up: what definition are you working with for the meaning of two continuous variables to being independent?

Comment: Proposition: Supppose that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly continous with joint pdf f(x,y). Then $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff $$f(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y), \ \ \forall x,y \in\mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: That works. In this situation, you don't know what $f(x,y)$ actually looks like, but you know that it can be factored as $f_X(x) f_Y(y)$. So, use that criterion in the expression I provided above and rearrange the integration to obtain the desired result.

Comment: So I have that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{y}f_X(x)f_Y(y) \ dxdy.$$ clearly, In order to obtain $F_X(x)$ I need to integrate $f_X(x)$ w.r.t $x$. But this will only give me $$\int_{0}^{\infty}F_X(y)f_Y(y) \ dy$$ which isn't exactly right.

Comment: The variable of integration is just a placeholder, so you can swap it out with $x$.

Answer (score 1):

In modern probability, conditional probability is define on special case of conditional expectation.

so define:

$A=\{\omega \in \Omega| X(\omega) < Y(\omega)\}$

$p(X< Y)= p(A)=E(I_A)=E(E(I_A|Y))=\int E(I_A|Y=y) f_Y(y) dy=\int E(I_{X< Y}|Y=y) f_Y(y) dy=\int E(I_{X< y}|Y=y) f_Y(y) dy\overset{independent}{=}
\int E(I_{X< y}) f_Y(y)dy=\int P(X< y) f_Y(y)dy
=\int F_X(y) f_Y(y)dy$

Note that $E(I_A|X)=E(Z|X)=E(Z|\sigma(X))$ is a predictor that satisfy
projection property and exists and unique.