# Find the CDF of $XY$ given CDF's of noncontinuous $X, Y$.

Tags: probability

For $X, Y$ independent random variables with CDF's $F_X, F_Y$ how would one go about finding the CDF of $XY$? I ask because the PDF's aren't necessarily defined ([wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) says $X$ needs to be continuous), and the every source I find online for finding $F_{XY}$ goes through the PDF's.

Comment: @lmaosome That's not how CDFs work.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables#Derivation_for_independent_random_variables) (bear in mind its $f$s are densities rather than CDFs).

Comment: thanks for spotting the error; dunno what I was thinking. sorry

Comment: Wikipedia says here $X, Y$ are continuous? If they aren't are thr $f$'s defined?

Comment: I think there is not enough details provided to answer this question. Do you have more detailed info on what you are working on? I mean, you can determine $P(XY<z)$ by integrating over the set $\{xy < z\}$, if you have density functions, like in this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2753675/show-that-pxy-int-0-infty-f-xxf-yx-dx?rq=1 But I guess it's hard to tell, from the information you provide, if that's possible. Do random variables always have densities in your course?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are not continuous, are they discrete? If they are neither continuous nor discrete, you will have to pray for finding the CDF of a continuous singular (a.k.a. degenerated) random variable is just hard.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and singular continuous random variables, then I would try to work it out with the characteristic functions $\phi_X$ and $\phi_Y$, which always exist.

Then by conditioning like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables#Characteristic_function_of_product_of_random_variables):
$$\phi_{XY}(t)=E[e^{itXY}]=E[E[e^{itXY}|Y]]=E[\phi_{X}(tY)]$$

And if I got that far, I could try to calculate $F_{XY}$ by using the [inversion formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Inversion_formulae).

But if $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are just mixed continuous and discrete random variables (no singular continuous component), you can decompose $X$ and $Y$ into their continuous and discrete parts like [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468806/how-to-decompose-a-cdf-into-discrete-and-continuous-parts), and work out $XY$ on components.

For example if:
$$F_X(t)=F_Y(t)=
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if } t<0\\
\frac{t}{2}+\frac{1}{2} &\text{ if } 0\le t<1\\
1 &\text{ if } t\ge1
\end{cases}$$

Then you could write $X$ as:
$$X=
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{ with probability } \frac{1}{2}\\
U_X &\text{ with probability } \frac{1}{2}\\
\end{cases}
$$
And the same for $Y$:
$$Y=
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{ with probability } \frac{1}{2}\\
U_Y &\text{ with probability } \frac{1}{2}\\
\end{cases}
$$

With $U_X$ and $U_Y$ i.i.d. uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$

Then:
$$XY=
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{ with probability } \frac{3}{4}\\
U_XU_Y &\text{ with probability } \frac{1}{4}\\
\end{cases}
$$
And $F_{XY}$ follows easily.

Comment: how would you go from $F_X$ to $\phi_X$?

Comment: Use Lebesgue-Stieljets integration: $\phi_X(t)=\int e^{itx} dF_X(x)$